# Include issue: header file not found in iOS project in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Consider my setup looks like this:

- XCode 4 iphone/ipad project
- ObjC .m file that includes a new header file, this header is reported as "file not found"
- ObjC .m file is located in root folder of the project
- new header file is also located in root folder of the project
- new header file was created within Xcode 4 as "C header file" (!!)

I tried using #import and #include statements with both "" and <> lookup syntax.
The project already consists of a bunch of other objC headers/classes and they work nicely. I suspect that creating the file as a C-style header is the issue.

I did explicitly NOT try to add a USER_PATH or anything like that, since it's all happening in the root project folder.

Any ideas? I'm really surprised how complicated such simple things can get!

! Additional comment: (EDIT)

I now verified that I can create any type of header (menu "new file"->"C/C++"->"header") and it will never be found by objective-C code. Even a new clean project behaves the same! What kind of feature is this?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdness.

I talked to a bunch of fellow Xcode sufferers and they confirmed I HAVE to set the extra path variable. Their explanation was a bit odd though: in objectiveC the lookup (import) simply scans the whole subfolder structure, whereas an 'include' does not. From my point of view this would only be a valid argument if the header file in question was located in a subfolder! But mine is in the exact same location as the '.m' file!

Comment: I don't want to confirm my own answer.. so not setting it to "accepted".

Comment: Hi,  what do you mean by "I HAVE to set the extra path variable"?  How do you set the path variable?  Are you talking about setting the Header Search Paths in Xcode->Project->Build Settings->Search Paths->Header Search Paths?  If so, how do you enter the path variable?  Is there a $_SOME_VARIABLE_NAME format?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad: I actually meant that the path in question is set in the header search path. The term "variable" is derived from the fact that I consider the whole UI of Xcode just messing around with the compiler build path settings (aka 'variables'). I honestly prefer text files to configure the build environment over the zillion sub-menus of Xcode, since I consider this much easier to digest/comprehend.